# Can SSIS check record that is imported during the current run

Tags: ssis

I am importing multiple users. Each user can belong to multiple companies. So from Source I will get rows like these

```
userId  companyID  userinfo   companyinfo
123      abc       blah       blah
123      def       blah       blah
456      abc       blah       blah
789      xyz       blah       blah
```

I have a **Lookup Component** to check if user already created in the new system. If not create a user in the User Table. If it is, then just add a row in the userid-companyid-relationship table.

My question is does ssis works like that? i.e. it import data row by row. 
first it import (123, abc, blah, blah). Then when it import (123, def, blah, blah), it realize userid: 123 already in the User Table. Or does it do some kind of bulk import, and anything that is added during the current iteration, the Lookup Component wont be able to pick up, because to him Userid: 123 doesnt exist yet?

Im having some issue with my package, it seems like my lookup component is not working properly, I was wondering if it is because of the concern I just mention.

Hope this make sense.
Thanks

Comment: That is what the `Cache Mode` of the lookup component configures. Ref: [Lookup cache modes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattm/2008/10/18/lookup-cache-modes/). Read what it says for when you should use No Cache vs Partial vs Full Cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian's comment about Cache Mode is spot-on, but I would add that in my experience the best way to handle things like this in SSIS is to import all of the data into a staging table, and then handle the lookups and relationship-creation in a stored procedure on the SQL Server.  These kinds of things go much faster in TSQL than they do in SSIS.   SSIS is fastest when it's simplest.

Comment: My manager doesnt want us to create too many staging table. Also I tried the no cache method. also disabled bulk import, however Im still having issue. Could it be because it's too "fast". Say the extra record come right after the original record. So before the original even finish inserting, it checks the extra record against the reference table and since the original record is not done inserting, it will think it's not an extra row and insert the extra record?

Comment: According to the documentation, "no cache" should be processed row-by-row and I've never had the problem you describe using it.   You might try changing your "Rows per Batch" property to 1, to force the data flow to process 1 row at a time.  It will probably be much slower, but I guess your manager would find that preferable to creating another staging table.